# How to find the volume of the solid using Disc Method

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, solid-of-revolution

Using disc method, how to find the volume of the solid generated when the region bounded by $y^2 = x$ and the line $x = 2y$ is revolved about the line $y = -2$?

So far, I have obtained the bounds $(0,2)$ from $y^2 = 2y$ and the distance $y^2 + 2$ from $|y^2 - (-2)|$ but I am not sure if what I obtained is correct

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please let us know what you have tried so far. Otherwise your question will probably be closed.

Comment: So far, I have obtained the bounds (0,2) from y^2 = 2y and the distance ^2 + 2 from  |^2 - (-2)|  but I am not sure if what I obtained is correct.

Comment: Can you include it in the body of the question?

Comment: If you use disc method, you are integrating along $x$, parallel to the axis of revolution $y=-2$. Your bounds $(0,2)$ are the minimum and maximum $y$; you should instead find the minimum and maximum $x$ where the discs (or washers) stack. The radii of the discs should also be in terms of $x$.